# show hide youtube video on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

**Q1)** On page load is it possible with Jquery to check the file name of the image and then set the css to position it on the page?

**Q2)** What is the easiest way to manage this, the user will not be embedding the iframe code inside the div.icon

I have a play button icon which will be in the product description in an ecommerce website. When the user clicks play it will show the youtube video exactly inside the product-image div box. The icon will be positioned next to the image nav icons so the user has an option to see the video while browsing the pics.

It seems to work nice here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="product-image"><img src=
    "http://www.skriftlig.com/konfliktmegling/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/Photoxpress_2658886-480x220.jpg"
    alt=
    "http://www.skriftlig.com/konfliktmegling/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/Photoxpress_2658886-480x220.jpg" /></div>

    <div class="image-nav"></div>

    <div class="icon">
      <iframe width="480" height="220" src=
      "http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/jvTv_oatLA0?rel=0" frameborder="0"
      allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.container
{
    margin:10px 10px auto;
    border:1px solid orange;
}

div.product-image
{
    height:220px;
    width:480px;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:30px;      
}

div.image-nav
{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    margin:30px;
}

div.icon
{
    background-image: url("http://i46.tinypic.com/zmmbo8.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 50px;
    left: 540px;
    position: relative;
    top: -104px;
    width: 50px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

div.icon iframe
{
    display:none;
    position:relative;
    top:30px;
}

div.product-image iframe
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 42px;
    left:42px;
}
```

**JQ:**

```
var $video=$('div.icon iframe');
var $productImage=$('.product-image');
var $icon=$('.icon');
$icon.on('click',function()
{
    $('.product-image').append($video);
});
```

**jsfiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/t7qMF/2/

Comment: This for **Q1**, to set the style of image according to its path or image name, something like this: `$('img[src="Path to image"]').css(some_css_property,"value");`.

Not got you in Q2.

Comment: Q2- how does someone who doesnt know HTML able to paste the iframe code with the div??? I am looking for a solution for this handicap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Q1 Ishan is rigth you can use:

```
$('img[src="images/test.png"]').css("position","absolute");
```

For Q2: A youtube embed code looks like this:

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0">
```

You can try using the iframe class to select it:

```
var $video=$('iframe.youtube-player');
var $productImage=$('.product-image');
var $icon=$('.icon');
$icon.on('click',function()
{
    $('.product-image').append($video);
});
```

Then on the onload event you have to add some jquery thats gonne wrap every youtube iframe with your icon div. I'm not sure but this could be something like:

```
$(function() {
     $('iframe.youtube-player').each(function(){
         var $iconDiv = $(this).parent().append('<div class="icon"></div>');
         $(this).prependTo($iconDiv);
     });
});
```

Hope this help's

Comment: Thanks thats cleared a few things up. The  thing is the user is just going to take the youtube iframe and paste it into the description section. So i need to check if the iframe exists then append it to the div.icon Which i think your JQ code is doing?

Comment: Q1_ adding a class would be better i think.

Comment: I agree addClass would be way better. And yes that's what my code is doing. I'm not sure because i didn't test it yet. If my answer helped please accept it :-) thanks.

Comment: are you any good with css? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135287/fluid-width-menu-using-css